Canceled or Cancelled
I recently noticed that one of the applications I manage had first used "Canceled" as a status and then switched to "Cancelled." I went searching for what is correct. As per Merriam Webster - both are correct. https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/canceled-or-cancelled
Now, our company is a US firm but most of the people using the application are based outside of the US. So, do we follow US spelling/ terms/ cultural icons or non US ones?
Any suggestions on how to address it?

Although copy is part of the UX, you may get good answers about language usage from English Language Learners or English Language & Usage as well.

Personally I would use the spelling and grammar that is relevant to the most common nationality of users on your platform. For example, say if your user base is 60-70% UK users, then you would use "colour" instead of "color". However, if UK as the largest group was say only 30-40% but there was a big mix of other countries, then I would probably default to US English as the majority of other countries will refer to that for English spelling.

In addition to considering which nationality the audience is mostly comprised of, the other driving factor in this is the brand guidelines. If the brand guidlines, particularly called Content Guide, stipulate American English as the standard, it is what the default language should be. If it is a US firm, it is understandable to use American English and different spelling should not offend any user because the message conveyed remains the same. Unless the two words mean completely different things or turn out to be offensive in some nation, it should not be a worry.
